# Angular TranslateService translate <title> tag

Tags: angular, typescript

Using the `TranslateService` in Angular I want the `<title>` tag which sits in the `index.html`  to be in different languages.

```
<title translate>application.title</title>
```

I translate all other html tags like that unless they are custom html tags then it's like this:

```
{{"document.name"|translate}}
```

The problem might be that index.html is in a different level in the folders

src
|-app
....  |-translation
|-index.html

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Title-class.html):

> ## `Title`
>
> Since an Angular application can't be bootstrapped on the entire HTML document (`<html>` tag) it is not possible to bind to the text property of the HTMLTitleElement elements (representing the `<title>` tag). Instead, this service can be used to set and get the current title value.

You just need to use the `Title` service in combination with `TranslateService`

```js
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private title:Title, private translate:TranslateService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.translateService.get("document.name").subscribe(name=>{
      this.title.setTitle(name);
    });
  }
}
```

Please, also take a look at [this cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am using ngx-translate with xliffmerge to prevent overwriting existing text and automatically add new texts to the xlf file. But text is only added if it exists in a template. Therefore the accepted answer is not what I want.

Instead I have created a directive that I can use to add the title in a html element on every page. The title is now automatically translated and the directive then grabs the text and changes the title via Angulars title service.

The directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterContentInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Directive({
  selector: '[edHeadTitle]'
})

export class HeadTitleDirective implements AfterContentInit{

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,private titleService: Title) {}

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    this.titleService.setTitle(this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }

}
```

Then on any page (component) which must change the title, e.g. the page displaying terms:

```
<h2 edHeadTitle i18n class="headerTitle">Terms and conditions</h2>
```

If you don't want the title to display on the page, just set "display:none" in the headerTitle css class.

Comment: Using Angular 9, this can be achieved much better. check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61006883/3160597