# How to translate text from .ts file using Angular 7 standard translation

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization, angular7

We are using the Angular 7 standard for internationalization (.xlf files). If we have text on html files with i18n attributes in tags, we can translate without issues. However, if we need to return different messages depending on some conditions (i.e.: validations) from code (.ts), we don't know how to translate that code.

Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Angular i18n to translate string literals in typescript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124757/can-i-use-angular-i18n-to-translate-string-literals-in-typescript-code)

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56075872/4399281